# Showing that the sum of the angles of a hyperbolic triangle are less than $\pi$

Tags: geometry, triangles, hyperbolic-geometry

Using the law of cosines for sides:

$\cosh(a) = \cosh(b) \, \cosh(c) - \sinh(b) \, \sinh(c) \, \cos(\alpha) $

I have to show that

$\alpha + \beta + \gamma < \pi$

Unfortunately I find no ansatz for this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing that sum of angles of hyperbolic triangle is strictly less than $\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2369679/showing-that-sum-of-angles-of-hyperbolic-triangle-is-strictly-less-than-pi)

Comment: I think you're mixing $a,b,c$ and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$.

Comment: This problem is trickier than it looks.  In spherical geometry the corresponding Law of Cosines retrieves $\alpha+\beta+\gamma>180°$ by comparing the spherical triangle with a planar one having sides $\sin(a/2),\sin(b/2),\sin(c/2)$; the planar triangle will have smaller angles than the spherical one.  But here, the apparent comparison triangle with hyperbolic sines for the side lengths may not exist!

Comment: @JitendraSingh unfortunately not. I strictly have to use the upper equation.

Comment: @Arthur no the equation is true.